# Angularjs : Hide scrollToRow button if the row is appearing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't know if it's possible. So I have a table with severals rows and a button that allow me to scroll until a specific row.

The thing is there is no point showing this button if the row I want to scroll to is already showing on my current screen and it should be displayed only if the user wants to come back to it.

So :

```
<button ng-click="goToRow()">Go to NeyYork row</button>
```

should be something like :

```
<button ng-show="rowOnScreen" ng-click="goToRow()">Go to NeyYork row</button>
```

But really don't know how should I handle the `ng-show` inside the button.

**Edited fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/BrTzg/601/

Answer (score 0):

You must somehow determine if element is in viewport or not. 
I will skip details and provide You with directive which might be helpful.

[InView Directive for AngularJS](https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview)

Comment: The point is , how can I watch for this specific row and not others

Comment: Maybe try to place conditionally element inside it and stick directive to that element. Otherwise try to apply directive conditionally...